# java error ';'C:\Users\shailesh\Desktop>javac test1.java test1.java:3: error: ';' expected package Program Files.Java.jdk1.7.0_71.bin;

Tags: java

my program :

```
public class test1{
    public static void main(string[]args){
        system.out.println("u are goin to be java pro very soon");
    }
}
```

I am getting error in CMd;

```
C:\Users\shailesh\Desktop>javac test1.java
test1.java:3: error: ';' expected
package Program Files.Java.jdk1.7.0_71.bin;
           ^
1 error
```

Please suggest I am new to java.

Comment: Why did you write `package Program Files.Java.jdk1.7.0_71.bin;`?

Comment: You don't *require* packages right now.  If you remove that statement, what you've got are two very simple typos.

Comment: Also change system to System - upper case S will be required - and string to String

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print something in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705499/how-to-print-something-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Remove everything from whatever IDE you are using and just paste this(No Imports or any package name needed):

```
public class test1{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        System.out.println("u are goin to be java pro very soon");
    }
}
```